# App Store returns previous version which is different from current version

Tags: react-native

I built a `React-Native` app where app version is shown to user. My `iOS` app's current **App Store** version is `1.0.2` which is being shown in the **App Store Connect** itself. But when when I tried to fetch the version by using following query,

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=${bundleID}
```

result is showing as `1.0.1`.

I checked this immediately after update is happened.

Is there any window time to check the app version after updating in **App Store Connect** or Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is the 1.0.2 version already on the shelves?

Comment: @M_JSL it's available in App Store Connect and even it contains the updated code(I tested it).